# Can I know if a link in a email was clicked in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to track my sent emails in Rails. I searched and discovered that I can do somethings like [this](https://myles.eftos.id.au/blog/2013/08/25/track-email-opens-using-a-pixel-tracker-from-rails/#.WeUu4nXys8q). But I also need to know if a specific link in the email was clicked. Is this possible?
Another idea I had is to know where the user was before the page. For example, the link takes you to page X. Can i know where the user was just before the page X - so I would be able to know if was an email page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to know if the user clicked the link via the sent email. A simple solution to this can be using an extra parameter in the links sent via the email. Something like `?email=true`. This way, you can retrieve this email parameter in your controller and know the user clicked the link in the email.

Your `request.referer` will be nil if redirected from an email. So this technique of checking the user's previous page will not work